WooCommerce - check if automated taxes are enabled
I set up an environment with WooCommerce and WooCommerce Shipping & Tax. The latest adds the option Automated taxes in WooCommerce tax settings.
I tried to retrieve the value of this option in my plugin. It looks like I cannot use instructions like get_option('sample_option') since this is not stored in wp_options table.
I also looked for a method in WC_Tax class, but I didn't find it.
